# Metaball not appearing when added

Tags: meta-objects, metaballs

Metaballs or any other meta object don't appear when I add them but the adjustment rings around them do. I've seen people having problems with them not appearing in a render but mine never appear. They are not hidden in the collections.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this also happen in a new blend file with the default cube?

Comment: No, when I open a new blender file I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've fixed it. I had to create a new collection for the meta object and then rename the object.